# Awk replacement pieces size limit

Tags: awk, size

Trying to find a single word and replace it with the contents of a file. Works on MacOS, but not under linux.

Here is the awk that fails under linux:

```
awk -v var="${blah}" '{sub(/%WORD%/,var)}1' file.xml
```

(file.xml is 122 lines, 4.7K)

Error is:

```
awk: program limit exceeded: replacement pieces size=255
```

Same file.xml under MacOS, using a slightly different awk works fine:

```
awk -v var="${blah//$'\n'/\\n}" '{sub(/%WORD%/,var)1}'
```

Recompiling awk is not an option. This is Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit.

Comment: You havent said how big `blah` is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed

```
FILE=`cat Filename`
sed  "s/WORD/${FILE}/g" file.xml > newfile.xml
```

Comment: That will not work as file.xml contains characters that sed tried to interpret as commands. Error is "sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command"

Comment: You should not use old and obsoleted back tics, use parentheses `$(...)`. `FILE=$(cat Filename)`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that good old 'replace' out performs awk in this use case--who would have thought?

```
replace -v "%WORD%" "$blah" -- file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Gnu Awk version 4, and the `readfile` extension:

```
gawk -f a.awk file.xml
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
@load "readfile"
BEGIN{
    var = readfile("blah")
    if (var == "" && ERRNO != "")
        print("problem reading file", ERRNO) > "/dev/stderr"
}
{
    sub(/%WORD%/,var)
    print
}
```